# Load more button and seo

Tags: asp.net-mvc, seo

In an image gallery website something like the photo stream in flickr we decided that we will use the Load More button as in [yahoo images search](http://images.search.yahoo.com/search/images;_ylt=A0oG7k.yM49PAnUA8hRXNyoA?p=car&fr=yfp-t-701&fr2=piv-web) instead of the paging functionalty.

But we have one concern about the Load More button, it is about the SEO, as I know search engines will not catch this button and index the images which will show after the user press on it, because everything will happen in ajax way without page refresh.

Is there an idea to make this button SEO friendly? is there any existing website did this before to see how it is working?

I am building my website using MVC.net, jQuery, C# and EF4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should implement a classical paging system for the search engines, then use Javascript to convert it to a Load More button.
This is called progressive enhancement.

Comment: great, can you give me a sample website, or an article talking about this in details?

Comment: By the way i think i got it, I will make the Load More button as a link which go to next page with page refresh, and add js code "will run if js is enabled" which will catch the click on this button and call the same request but ajax and load images without refresh.